# Lighttpd: config/rules for a subdirectory in same directory (like Apache's .htacces)?

Tags: configuration, directory, rules, lighttpd

Fairly new to lighttpd, came from the Apache camp. With Apache you can place a `.htaccess` file in any directory providing some additional rules to a project. This is not possible with lighttpd?

Tried:

- subdir/lighttpd.conf.d
- subdir/lighttpd.conf
- subdir/lighttpd.d

And `subdir/subdir.<conf.d|conf|d>` etc, nothing seems to work. This is not possible with lighttpd? I need to edit the  `/etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf` for each project in a subdirectory?

Answer (score 0):

Lighttpd isn't Apache, so you have to get used to the lighttpd way of doing things like this. Unfortunately and this turns off a lot of people from Lighttpd it doesn't have am equivalent of .htaccess.

Lighttpd also has just one central configuration file. However it does have the concept of `includes` so should you want a separate config file for each of your virtual hosts you could do the following:

In your `/etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf` set up each of your vhosts like this:

```
$HTTP["host"] == "example.com" {
    include "example.com.conf"
}
```

And then you can create a separate config for each of your vhosts in this case `/etc/lighttpd/example.com.conf` like this:

```
## set up php
fastcgi.server = ( ".php" => ((
    "bin-path" => "/usr/bin/php-cgi",
    "socket" => "/tmp/php-" + PID + ".socket"
)))

## redirect non-www to www
$HTTP["host"] =~ "^example\.com$" {
    url.redirect = ( "^/(.*)" => "https://www.example.com/$1" )
}

## Domain specific rewrites
url.rewrite-if-not-file = (
    "^/(.*)$" => "/index.php/$1"
)

## Deny Access
$HTTP["url"] =~ "^/secrets" {
        url.access-deny = ("")
}
```

The benefit of doing things this way is you can have a custom config for particular vhost setups. For example a seperate config for php, one for wordpress, one for nodejs etc etc. Like so:

```
$HTTP["host"] == "wordpress.example.com" {
    include "php.conf"
    include "wordpress.conf"
}

$HTTP["host"] == "nodeapp.example.com" {
    include "nodejs.conf"
}
```

In this example the php.conf would include all your fastcgi setup, wordpress.conf all your wordpress rewrites and nodejs.conf all the proxy setup to your node application.